# Django Admin tabularInline very slow request

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have Location app in my project. There are list of countries, their states and cities.

model.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Country'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'
        unique_together = ['name', 'iso2'],

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name=_('Country name'),
    )

    iso2 = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('iso2'),
    )

    phone_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Phone code'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name=_('State'),
    )

    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name=_('Country'),
        related_name='states',
        related_query_name='states',
        null=True,
    )

    state_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('State code'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=70,
        verbose_name=_('City name'),
    )

    state = models.ForeignKey(
        State,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_('State'),
        related_name='cities',
        related_query_name='cities',
    )

    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name=_('Country'),
        related_name='cities',
        related_query_name='cities',
        null=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm trying to get list of country cities in Django admin via Tabular inline, but when I click on any country it loads very slow (about 1 minute). How to optimize it? 
When I did it in Shell - `Country.objects.get(name='USA').cities.all()`  it returns results less than 10ms

admin.py

```
from .models import Country, City


class CountryCitiesAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = City


class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (CountryCitiesAdmin,)
    list_display = ('name', 'iso2', 'phone_code')
    search_fields = ('name', 'code', 'phone_code',)


admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)
```

Comment: Note: I have about 140k cities in city-table

Comment: Please try installing the django-debug-toolbar and use the SQL panel to view the number of queries and the queries being generated.

Comment: @schillingt Thank you for response. I've tried Zimbabwe. This country has 106 cities in my DB. django-debug-toolbar results: 241 queries in 10301 ms

Comment: SELECT "locations_state"."id",
       "locations_state"."name",
       "locations_state"."country_id",
       "locations_state"."state_code"
  FROM "locations_state"
  226 similar queries.   Duplicated 226 times.

Comment: Do you need to edit it? You could use read_only in admin.py

Comment: @errorinpersona no, I do not. I'll try it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use the [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) property. What's happening is that it's pulling all of the possible values to populate the `select` html element. Setting `raw_id_fields = ['country', 'state']` will make it an input that shows the ID of the instance instead.

Comment: I added `raw_id_fields` to TabularInline class and it started works faster, but still doing duplicate queries. I removed State class and leave only Country -> Cities relation and now it works fine. I don't have idea why it works with duplicate queries when I have Country -> States -> Cities relation